# How to add custom errorformat at the beginning of the list

Tags: quickfix, errorformat, list

I added  a custom `errorformat` in my .vimrc like this:

```
set errorformat+=ERROR:\ %f:%l:%c:\ error:\ %m
```

However, this doesn't work because an already existing format is matched first (incorrectly). In order to prioritize my own format I'd like to add it to the beginning of the `errorformat` list but haven't found a way to do so. I checked `:h list` but that didn't help or maybe I'm looking in the wrong spot. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `:h set^=` maybe?

Comment: @MaximKim Yes, that's it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MaximKim let's turn that into an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set errorformat^=ERROR:\ %f:%l:%c:\ error:\ %m`

For string option `^=` would prepend given value to existing one.

See `:h set^=` for reference.